# JavaScript and Modal Dialogs

Tags: javascript, jquery

A JavaScript function that needs to prompt a user for some data, and then submit that data via Ajax.  Coming from a WinForms/WPF background, my first thought was to do something like this:

```
function promptForData() {
    $('#my-form').dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "OK": function () {
                alert("Added");
                // Unlike WinForms I cannot
                // set a dialog result here
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                alert("Canceled");
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
}

function update() {
    var data = promptForData();
    // Unlike WinForms execution continues immediately even
    // for a "modal" dialog (jQuery UI Dialog, modal: true)
    makeAjaxCall(data);
}
```

The obvious solution seems to be to restructure the code so that `makeAjaxCall(data)` happens in the "OK" handler of the dialog.

Since the actual code involved is significantly more complex, I do hope to separate prompting for the data from using the data.  Is there a suitable pattern for doing that?

*Note: The actual implementation shown uses jQuery UI, but I think the problem is independent of that.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic pattern for this is representing the "what to do next" with a callback parameter. Instead of returning values from your prompt function, call the callback with those values and instead of putting the return value of the prompt function in a variable you put it in an argument to the callback.

```
function promptForData(callback) {
    $('#my-form').dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "OK": function () {
            alert("Added");
            // Unlike WinForms I cannot
            // set a dialog result here
            $(this).dialog("close");

            callback(/*pass your data here*/); // <----
        },
        "Cancel": function () {
            alert("Canceled");
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
}

promptForData(function(data){
    makeAjaxCall(data)
})
```

If you do lots of async stuff this can start to get a bit ugly though, since the callbacks have a tendency to "nest" inside each other, creating a "pyramid of doom". If you run into that I would suggest having a look at the Promise/Deferred pattern.

Note that I also did not cover error handling here. When writing "callbacky" code if something can throw an exception you need to add immediately add a try/catch block so you can catch it and pass it to a separate error callback. Again, you might want to look into Promises if this becomes a problem for you.

Comment: The "pyramid of doom" was exactly what I feared :-)